# [Rotativa]Exporting to pdf empty - when applying Search filter to partial view table

Tags: c#, asp.net, rotativa

The issue is: Im using rotativa to export html table to pdf.
When exporting without filter is exporting ok(ish) but when applying filter like search is coming out empty.

The table is in a partialView and the rows are generated by a Foreach.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PrintViewToPdf()
    {
        var model = new List<HistoricoEmpleados>();
        var report = new PartialViewAsPdf("_ReporteEmpleados", model)
        {
            FileName="Empleados.pdf",
            PageSize = Size.A4,
            PageOrientation = Orientation.Portrait,
            PageMargins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0),
            PageWidth = 210,
            PageHeight = 297


        };


        return report;
    }
```